# Spring mongo group operation

Tags: spring, mongodb

We couldn't able to get the severity ...we are getting the severity count alone.we need to use lookup and group operation together.

```
    LookupOperation lookupp = LookupOperation.newLookup()
                    .from("defect").localField("defid").foreignField("defid")
                    .as("defectsLst");


            MatchOperation match = new MatchOperation(Criteria
                    .where("projectid").is(projectid)
                    .andOperator(Criteria.where("type").is("File")));


    GroupOperation group = new GroupOperation (Fields.fields("$defectsLst.severity"))
.count().as("sevCount");


                Aggregation agg =  Aggregation.newAggregation(lookupp,
                         match,group);
```

Comment: [`group()`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.group/) and [`aggregate()`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/) are two completely different things. You are trying to mix the two. if you want [`$lookup`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) then you want `.aggregate()` instead. You need to include all of the context of the operation you actually want to run when posting here. Please [Edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/44581928/edit) to provide the context so people can help.

Comment: Also see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in the StackOverflow help center

Comment: Thanks for your reply.please give an example how to use lookup and group in spring mongodb 1.9.5 version

Comment: Can you add some documents from both the collections and expected json output ?